# Highlight buttons on search - Android

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to implement search functionality in my app. The only difference is that I am not implementing search to search a listview. I want to highlight buttons on search. In my app activity, I have 100 small buttons. On the top, there is an edittext which has to search the buttons and highlight them. How can I achieve it?

Comment: you can create a highlight function which changes the drawable for button provided in paramaeter , and can pass all the button objects that need to be highlighted depending upon particular search

Answer (score 1):

Nice concept.

here is your arryadepter

```
private class List_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
private ArrayList<Sring> items; // this is your all buttons list
private ArrayList<String> itemsPosition; // this is your highlight list

public List_Adapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Sring> la, final ArrayList<String> itemsPosition)
{
super(context, textViewResourceId, la);
this.items = la;
this.itemsPosition = itemsPosition;
}

public View getView(final int rowIndex, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
if (itemsPosition!=null)
{
for (int j = 0; j < itemsPosition.size(); j++)
{
final String textOut = itemsPosition.get(j);
if (items.getTag().contains(textOut))
{
//  hilight your view
}
}
}

return v;
}
}
```

and here is your edittext listioner

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence chrSeq, final int start, final int before, final int count)
{
if (edittext.getText().length() == 0)
{
listAdapter = new List_Adapter(thisActivity, R.layout.existingcaregiverlistview, chemical name arry,chemical eliment arry);
listOfCaregiver.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
else
{
final ArrayList<String> arraySort = new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength = 0;
textlength = edittext.getText().length();
arraySort.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++)
{
if (edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains((String) mainList.get(i).getTag().toString().toLowerCase().subSequence(0, textlength)))
{
arraySort.add(mainList.get(i))
}
}
listAdapter = new List_Adapter(thisActivity, R.layout.existingcaregiverlistview, chemical name arry,chemical eliment arry);
listOfCaregiver.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
});
```

Comment: +1 thanks a lot for your help. I will try it out. but there is one confusion. My buttons have the initials of the text. Suppose i have a facebook button, the button text only has F. So then how can i carry out the search? Please advise. thanks!

Comment: in that case you have to use view.setteg(String) method to identify buttons

Comment: OK thanks! I'll use view.setTag(String) method to identify buttons. Can you please please provide me with an example? I am beginner!

Comment: is your buttons list have some class or model ?

Comment: hmmmm. so when are you going to fill your ArrayList at time you have to tag some string like F for facebook, G for google etc...

Comment: I am not getting you. can you please give me an example code of what you are tring to say?

Comment: Please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320013/highlight-buttons-on-search

Comment: still not complete code. pls put your complete activity code.

Comment: No, there is no activity code. But I have made an array. I'll post it. Please check it!

Comment: ok make two array one for chemical name and other for chemical element

Comment: use this for (int i = 0; i < elename.length; i++)
     {
  chemical name arry .add(chemical name);
         chemical element arry .add(chemical element);
     }
pass it to adepter

Comment: The moethod getTag in listadapter class is not working.

Comment: remove it you dont need it any more

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I would recommend creating a [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for the drawable that you use for the button.  Then you can utilize one of the states (android:state_hovered maybe) as the highlight state.  When you run your filtering on any button that matches the search term change the state to that highlight state.

Comment: Thanks fine. But how do i perform the search in the first place?