# Highlight buttons on search

Tags: android, android-button, android-search

I am trying to implement search functionality in android to search for buttons. Usually, search is used to search `listviews` but I want to use it to search buttons. I have 118 buttons in my activity and there is an `edittext`(Search bar) on the top.  Each button represents the symbol of a chemical element.
eg :
 
Cu = Copper
Zn = Zinc
O = Oxygen 
F = Fluorine 
Cl = Chlorine
and 112 more....

This is what my activity looks like
 
(This screen shot is just to better explain my problem and it is not the actual activity)
[image]
This image just shows 6 buttons but I have 112 more. The search bar looks the same.

Now, this is what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

I want to instantly highlight the button which represents the typed element. The user will type the name of the element but the button which represents its symbol should be highlighted. How can I achieve this?

I read about `TextWatchers()` and the way to use them to search listviews :

```
searchbar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.listviewadapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
```

Here is the xml for the above screenshot.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Table_main"
    android:background="#000000">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:hint="Search" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="Zn"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="Cu"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="O"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="Cl"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="F"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="N"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the array that contains all the chemical element names:

```
final String[] elename ={"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Caesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","gadoliium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einsteinium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium","Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Ununtrium","Ununquadium","Ununpentium","Ununhexium","Ununseptium","Ununoctium"};
```

Please help me implementing search to search buttons!
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

create a function doSearchAction as mentioned below :

// perform search action need to be called on onSearch event i.e searchbar text watcher.

```
private void doSearchAction(List<Button> btnList)
        {
          resetAllButton();
        for(int i=0;i<btnList.size;i++)
        {
        Button btn = btnList.get(i);
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlight_img); 
        }
```

// reset all button to default drawables

```
   private void resetAllButton()
        {
    // reset all button to default value    
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drwable.normal_img)
    ....

    all_buttons.setBackgroundResource(R.drwable.normal_img)


        }
```

Comment: Thanks but what is `btnList.get(i)`?

Comment: @DroidFan It would be any collection to store the buttons that need to be highlighted. I used List of Buttons i.e simply array of buttons

Comment: Ok so in this case it would be `elename` right? Please check the update. thanks a lot. I'll try and let you know!

Comment: No it would be id of button (i.e respective android button objects) that need to be highlighted for particualr search